# JQuery Draggable Object Position Absolute Inside Scaled Container Causes Jumping Behavior How to stop it?

Tags: jquery, user-interface, draggable, drag

Old issue, but **still** an issue nonetheless.

I'm using JQuery Draggable inside a scaled container. I had to patch the dragging speed, but now I have to patch the jumpy behavior the draggable object exhibits when start and drag are initiated.

So far I have been unsuccessful.

Does anyone have a working solution?

```
$('.draggable').draggable({
        containment: ".canvas",
        start: function(event, ui) {
            var scaleFactor = .6;
            // Calculate the original position relative to the parent
            ui.originalPosition = {
                left: ui.position.left / scaleFactor,
                top: ui.position.top / scaleFactor
            };
        },
        drag: function(event, ui) {
            var scaleFactor = .6;
            var changeLeft = ui.position.left - ui.originalPosition.left;
            var newLeft = ui.originalPosition.left + changeLeft / scaleFactor;
            var changeTop = ui.position.top - ui.originalPosition.top;
            var newTop = ui.originalPosition.top + changeTop / scaleFactor;
            ui.position.left = newLeft;
            ui.position.top = newTop;                
        }
    });
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/webDsign/pen/JjxZyjw)